# How to refer to SRCROOT variable in .xconfig file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have a silly problem here. I'm trying to set headers search path in .xconfig file, and Xcode doesn't seem to like $(SRCROOT) variable. How am I supposed to refer to it properly?

This is how I do it now (doesn't work - nothing shows up in build settings):

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(SRCROOT)/../../someFolder"
```

This also doesn't work:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${SRCROOT}/../../someFolder"
```

This works so everything else seems to be ok:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "../../someFolder"
```

When I set the variable through the Build Settings panel it also works allright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version is syntactically correct (xcconfig seems to use the tcsh style for variable expansion).

Your second version, using curly braces to expand variables like using it in bash should also work.

Your third version is brittle, since it uses a relative path. You should create absolute paths, through basing it on $(SRCROOT) or other given paths.

You should check if the variables are expanding as you expect through inspecting them in Xcode's build settings.

Also ensure the xcconfig files have been correctly associated to the project and targets: in section "Configurations" in the "Info" tab of the project editor.

Comment: Well, the problem is that whatever I put into the xconfig file updates correctly in Build Settings, so everything must be wired properly. But when I put the $(SRCROOT) the field in Build Settings goes blank - so it does not expand properly apparently and I don't know why.

Comment: @konrad You may try the following: use your own var, say `PRJ_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = ...  ` This variable then shows in the Build Settings separately. Check the paths if they are correct.  Then, in Header Search Paths, use that variable, e.g. `$(inherited) $(PRJ_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS)`

Comment: Ok, I think I nailed it but I can't say I understand the mechanism. The build settings inheritance is something like: Default > Config.File > Project > Resolved. I had deleted everything incl. '$(inherited)' from the Project level and this somehow caused the SRCROOT not to expand correctly even at higher level. Putting it back solved the problem. Fun fact: any other string e.g. "bill-gates" did work just the variable expansion didn't, that's why I thought I messed up the syntax. Xcode sure is a lot of joy to work with. Anyway the answer is correct - I just asked a wrong question :-)

Comment: @konrad Need to correct myself: the curly braces actually do work, too, since a long time ;)